# Seeking title and/or author of dystopian science-fiction novel from late-70s/early-80s

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

In the novel, humans all lived underground and were decanted - not born, were undersized, short-lived, emotionally-empty, and prone to suicide and freak-outs. Above ground there were mechanized factory farms of mono-cultures with no native life remaining; a single robotic whale swam the oceans. In the denouement, a number of long voyage space ships returned to reseed the planet with a genetic library sent from far in the past.

I read it in the mid-1980s on the the heels of reading "Ecotopia" which seems to have eclipsed any memory of the title for this book. Any ideas?

Comment: In re: the title. It's not like there are many to chose from or anything.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/book-about-a-man-whos-cut-in-half-placed-in-suspended-animation (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 9):

Could it be [The Godwhale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godwhale) by [T.J. Bass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._J._Bass)?  Although there isn't any mention of space ships I believe it is the whale that is tasked with repopulating the oceans.

Comment: I recognised elements of this as Bass's story Rorqual Maru, which I read in the anthology The 1973 Annual World's Best SF. On investigation, it seems that the story was an extract from The Godwhale. (Coincidentally, the answer to [this recent question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere) was also in that anthology.)

Comment: I looked up 'The God Whale' and it is very similar sounding and could be the correct title. I'll have to read it and see - sounds interesting even if it proves to not be the same book.

Comment: It sounds more like *The Godwhale*, but Bass's novel *Half Past Human* is set on the same world and has similar themes. I seem to recall *The Godwhale* only had one starship, which arrived at the beginning of the novel, while *Half Past Human* had one that arrived at the end.