# Couples sent on near-light speed trip to see how they're affected

Tags: story-identification

Earth sends a few (4?) couples on a short near-light speed round trip to see how they are affected, not telling them some important facts.  They evolve very rapidly, first dropping all social mores, then increasing in intelligence/power well beyond Earth people, arriving home angry(?). Was included in a collection with a short by John Varley (Persistence of Vision).

Comment: Are you 100% sure it appeared in a collection with John Varley's ["Persistence of Vision"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41070)?

Comment: Because your description reminds me of Pohl's ["The Gold at Starbow's End"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38022) which has been the answer to [previous questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere) on this site, but the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) does not seem to show any collections that contain both "Starbow" and "Persistence".

Comment: Oops, wrong link. Here is the the [ISFDB page](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51188) which lists the collections where Pohl's novella "The Gold at Starbow's End" has appeared.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's it!  I guess my memory is creating a collection that doesn't exist, but it was a long time ago.  I probably read them close together.

Comment: Great! If "The Gold at Starbow's End" turns out **not** to be the right story, please post another question, and (if possible) try to provide more details.