# Astronauts get mental improvement in space, return with amazing tech

Tags: story-identification, powers

science fiction theme : astronauts return with  fantastic technology after a short time in space after learning how to think better after leaving earth.

Short story 40-60 years ago : name ? author?

Comment: This is incredibly vague. Do you remember the cover, if it's a short story or full novel, in an anthology, any additional details? If you do, [edit] them in so we can help.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a rather wild guess based on your very limited info, I'll go with "[The Gold at the Starbow's End](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf1033)" by Frederik Pohl.

The description from the link:

> A short story based on an interesting premise that at some point in
>   the (near) future, mankind will stop making interesting, fundamental
>   discoveries because we have too much knowledge and too much apparatus
>   around us. In the story, the Americans launch eight astronauts in a
>   spaceship on a ten-year journey to Alpha Centauri to land on its
>   habitable planet called “Alpha-Aleph”. The trouble is, the planet does
>   not exist and the spaceship has only sufficient fuel to reach the star
>   system. More damningly, the American President and a very small circle
>   of science and political advisors have sanctioned this one-way suicide
>   mission, fully aware that the planet does not exist.
>
> The rationale for proceeding with this 40-billion dollar hoax is the
>   strong desire to advance fundamental knowledge, backed by the theory
>   that if you throw together a small group of very intelligent people in
>   extended isolation, they will learn to use the meagre tools at their
>   disposal along with raw brain power to make new discoveries in
>   fundamental sciences, especially if such thought process is not aimed
>   at making specific discoveries. So the astronauts are taught basic
>   number theory and elements of human communication and told to think
>   about these as “recreational puzzles” during the long voyage. A
>   multi-billion dollar ivory tower in action.

If this is the story, it is a duplicate of this question "[Story featuring smart people sent on a space mission to nowhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere)"