# Story about children sent into space who return for revenge

Tags: story-identification, books

I vaguely remember a story (novella?) about a group of children with enhanced intelligence shot into space at relativistic speed where they develop almost mystical powers (at some point they use the I Ching), get pissed-off, bombard the Earth with radiation (?) and eventually return. At some point they use

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: At some point they use what?  It looks like your sentence got cut off there.

Comment: What is the "I ching"? Is it a misspelling or is there some history behind whatever that is? If there is history, then edit in what the history is.

Comment: The I Ching is an ancient Chinese text used for divination and has been in print across the globe for centuries.

Comment: This is probably Pohl's "The Gold at the Starbow's End", which has been asked about here a lot. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=gold+at+the+starbow%27s+end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Story featuring smart people sent on a space mission to nowhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere)

Comment: @shanu - our [current policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065) for closing story-id questions as duplicates requires both questions to have the same accepted answer

Comment: @fez, I have retracted my close vote until(if) the answer does get accepted

Answer (score 12):

It is [*The Gold at the Starbow's End*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51188) by [Frederik Pohl](1919 - 2013)[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl).

Plot synopsis from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold_at_the_Starbow%27s_End):

> The story is told with two narrative devices—reports from members of the crew of the U.S. Starship *Constitution* alternating with a traditional third-person narration of the activities back on Earth. The main protagonist of the activities on Earth is Dr. Dieter von Knefhausen, the scientist in charge of the U.S. space program.
>
> In the first report from the starship, the reader learns that the ship is approximately one month into a multi-year journey to the Alpha Centauri star system, where the crew will begin colonization of the planet Alpha-Aleph. Already, the crew is finding they have too much free time and have begun filling that time by studying various problems in mathematics. In the first narration of the action on Earth, the reader learns that society has become dystopian. The possibility of colonizing Alpha-Aleph is a source of hope for a better future.
>
> As the story progresses, the reader is told that the existence of the planet Alpha-Aleph is a hoax, perpetrated not only on the American people but also on the crew of the starship. The true purpose of the mission is to place the crew in a position where they will have nothing to do other than study mathematics. The hoax was the idea of Knefhausen, who believes that, if deprived of any other means of recreation, the crew will succeed in making scientific breakthroughs that will then be broadcast back to Earth. Knefhausen's theory proves true, but he learns that the crew quickly becomes bored with technological applications of their new-found mathematical prowess. Instead, they become increasingly interested in using it to develop their understanding of art and philosophy. These new understandings give the crew an unusual control over the physical universe and, by the end of the story, they have achieved god-like powers.

In the end they bombard the Earth with bosons to disable the power grid, and "take over".

Originally Published in "Analog" Magazine in March, 1972, this short story has been included in other anthologies as well.

In 1982, Pohl expanded the story into the 219 page novel "[Starburst](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1125)".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You need to identify the author and title of the work in your answer in case the comments are deleted and this no longer makes sense on its own.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: And quite a frequently asked one at that.  @brady_brady, you might like to edit your answer  to indicate that the story was expanded to novel length under the title Starburst.

Comment: I wonder if The mini-series Ascension was inspired by this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_(miniseries)