# Science fiction short story where a spaceship crew develops some kind of powers, through isolation and necessity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to remember the name of this story I read at least a decade ago. A spaceship is sent out to find a new world. But actually its secret purpose is for the crew to, in necessity and solitude, develop some kind of solution to what ails mankind. The story involves some kind of scene where there is a test where someone has to cross a room without touching the floor using only two pieces of wood that are not long enough, or something like that. The story is also partly told through communications sent back to earth from the ship. In the final communique they basically have found enlightenment and return to destroy the earth with their new powers.

Comment: I think it's The golf at the starbow's end by pohl, but I got an eye infection and can hardly see today!

Comment: Yessssssss that is almost certainly it!!! Thank you!

Comment: Hope your eye infection clears up, those suck. I recommend antibiotics.

Comment: @OscarMeyerweiner let us know if the story is The Gold at Starbows End so we can mark this as a duplicate of [Story featuring smart people sent on a space mission to nowhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere)

Comment: @Danny, imagine going all that way just to play golf.  :-)

Comment: Yes, Danny correct identified it as The Gold at Starbows End

Comment: @Pete I noticed my spelling error today haha! My eyes were streaming yesterday and I couldn't focus very well....so it goes